# Can cremating bodies cause black rain?

Tags: china, japan, pollution

There is speculation that the mysterious black rain that Japan had a few months ago was from China cremating bodies, and in particular, mass cremations from coronavirus victims.

- 7 News: [Coronavirus victims’ cremated bodies blamed on ominous black rain falling in Japan](https://7news.com.au/lifestyle/health-wellbeing/coronavirus-victims-cremated-bodies-blamed-on-ominous-black-rain-falling-in-japan-c-732371)

  > There are claims the sludge is the fallout from a mass incineration of coronavirus bodies in China, the aftermath of a nuclear test in North Korea or the result of fuel dumping from planes flying overhead.

  [...]

  > The most plausible explanation appears to be a recent fire at a plastics factory in Noda, in the neighbouring prefecture of Chiba, but this has not been confirmed either.
- Daily Mail: [Incinerated coronavirus bodies, North Korean missiles, and airplane spillages among theories to explain 'disturbing' black rain falling over Japan](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-8077787/Disturbing-black-rain-reported-falling-parts-Japan.html)

  > Another Twitter user wrote: 'Are they secretly burning the bodies of coronavirus victims?'.
- The Sun: [Sinister ‘black rain’ falls over Japan sparking conspiracy theories its caused by cremated coronavirus bodies](https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/11107857/black-rain-japan-conspiracy-cremated-coronavirus-bodies/)

Was this black sooty rain caused by mass cremations?

Comment: Probably the mass of the bodies would be far to small, but [biomass burning does contribute to black carbon](https://ec.europa.eu/jrc/en/publication/long-term-trends-black-carbon-biomass-and-fossil-fuel-combustion-detected-jrc-atmospheric).  Not sure if there are any forest fires in the area at the moment.  Perhaps a starting point for someone answering the question.

Comment: It seems to have been reported originally by https://soranews24.com/2020/03/04/black-rain-falls-over-parts-of-saitama-prefecture/ There apparently was a fire in a factory nearby but I haven't checked all the details yet.

Comment: Very nice. Yes, around this time there was also the reports of 21 million missing cell phone users, which really fueled this. However, I remember seeing recently that a probably reason for the cell phones was due to people cancelling their second phone during covid. I am not sure if this quite makes sense, but it seems at least somewhat "reasonable". During covid I would expect phone use to go up though.

Comment: The daily mail article provides a far more likely but far less exciting explanation: *"It later emerged that a 'gigantic' fire had broken out in Hasuda around the time of the rainfall. It was the blaze, at what is thought to be a large commercial building, that was speculated to be the cause of the black rain."*